# tfs build access to the path is denied

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

I created a build definition for my ASP.NET web forms project on my Visual Studio Online account, and when I queue a build for it it gives me this error (attached on the image)

Although the website is built local, and published online so it passes locally the build process

Edit: I've included the build definition details

[image: Error details for build process]

[image: Build Definition]

Comment: Can you share the build definition? What is the build drop location you're using?

Comment: I've added them now to the question, thank you

Answer (score 3):

It can happen sometimes when the build system tries to use as many cores as possible but ends up stepping on its toes.

Try to add the following switch to the MSBUILD arguments in the build definition: `/m:1`

It tells MSBUILD to use only one process to build. If it does not change anything, at least you'll have rooted out one possible cause.